# Subset a dataframe contains a list of vectors in its column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has list in one of its column.My r script is as follow.

```
 a3 <- c('pr1','pr2','pr3','pr4','pr5')
    inter <- list(c('ip1','ip10'),c('ip3','ip4','ip6'),c('ip5','ip6'),c('ip2','ip3','ip1','ip11'),'ip5')
    inter
    cbn <- cbind(a3,inter)
    mn <- data.frame(cbn)
```

now if i want to subset a datframe based on the condition 
in the 2nd column of dataframe then if i write

```
cnd <- lapply(mn$inter ,function(x) lapply(cmb , function(y) mn[x %in% cmb('ip1','ip10' ,]))
```

Then this will give me wrong result. I want list of dataframes where i will compare different vectors and it will give a subset of dataframe as a result where either one of the value is true or whole vector will hold true value. Please provide any help.

Comment: As it is, I think your code seems too complex. It's generally a bad idea to put a list in a data.frame. You tend to end up having the problem you are mentioning. Could you give us a broader idea of what you are trying to achieve? We might be in a better position to help.

Comment: @DJJ I want to compare a vector with the second column of a dataframe and when by comparison if there will be a single true or if there will be all the elements as true then i will fetch the corresponding entry in a3. So the 1 st row will get match with the vector so i will fetch the name of the entry in a3 column.

Comment: You explanation is sill not very clear to me.  I would transform the data in the following way.  `len_group <-  sapply(inter,length)`, then `data.frame(A=c(rep(a3,len_group)),B=unlist(inter))`. With the previous ouput it's easier to ask something from your data.frame.

Comment: For example `df[df$A=="pr1"&df$B%in% c("ip10","ip1"), ]`. I would recommend having a look at `data.table` package

Comment: @DJJ The way you suggested that is what i want. But i also want to check the which entries in mn$a3 will get an exact match with the given c("ip10", "ip1") so as a result it should return first row of mn that has the exact match with the given vector c("ip10" , "ip1").

Comment: What about `df <- data.frame(A=c(rep(a3,len_group)),B=unlist(inter))`, then `which(df$B %in% c("ip10","ip1"))`, then `which(df$B %in% c("ip10","ip1"))[1]`? Finally you could easily do `df[which(df$B %in% c("ip10","ip1"))[1],]`

Comment: @DJJ this will only work for 1st row of df. If i will change the vector from c("ip10","ip1") to c("ip3,ip4,ip6) then it should return the row with pr2. So this is not working for other rows.

Comment: precisely `df[which(df$B %in% c("ip3","ip4","ip6"))[1],]`

Comment: @DJJ Thank you so much it works fine. I was struggling for this issue since last so many days. This works exactly what i want.